# trigger nested click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a click only if another click (parent click) is activated. in other words, **Click-2** has to fire only if **click-1** is activated. so when I trigger **click-1** again, then **click-2** should not fire.
But my problem is, **click-2** still fire regardless of status of parent click after first trigger of **click-1**.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var c = 1;
        $('#click-1').on('click', function() {

                c++;
                if (c % 2 == 0) {
                    $('#Click-2').on('click', function(e) {
                        alert('Condition satisfied ')
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#Click-2').on('click', function(e) {
                        alert('condition did NOT satisfy')
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    });
                }

            )
        };

    )
};
```

I appreciate any help on this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the way to trigger the clicks. Here you are binding the click events in this code

```
$('#Click-2').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('Condition satisfied ')
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Instead, try `$("selector").trigger("click")` . Move the binding code out of the click handler. Have separate click handlers and avoid nested bindings.
And when you want to trigger a click on an element,let's say `#Click-2` then just use following inside the condition:

```
$("#Click-2").trigger("click");
```